# «Беззаветен и целеустремлён»

Tags: значение-слов, неологизмы

Наверное, это — из отзывов о новом «Викинге». Возникший вопрос не связан с фильмом никак. Нет ли у вас ощущения искусственности и противоречивости от этой пары слов. Что здесь не так?

Answer (score 1):

Слово "беззаветен" буквально означает "склонен доходить до самозабвения", поэтому при характеристиках индивида без странностей самостоятельно не используется. Оно лишь может придавать оттенок другому качеству, например, в старой идеологии широко применялся штамп "беззаветно преданный" - о безоговорочной и бескорыстной ("до самозабвения") преданности делу, родине и т. п. Со вторым словом таких проблем нет (напр. "бескорыстен и целеустремлён" - возможное сочетание качеств).

Answer (score 1):

**О слове беззаветный**

**1) Значение:**  БЕЗЗАВЕТНЫЙ,  Высок. Чуждый всякого расчёта; самоотверженный.

**2) Этимология:** Образовано сложением предлога и слова завет, имевшего значение "условие"; таким образом, **изначальное значение слова беззаветный – "безусловный".**

**3) Синонимы:** а) положительное значение: самоотверженный, жертвенный;    б) другое: безусловный, безоглядный, а эти качества могут иметь разные люди, например:  Броситься же на «авось» с армией на неприятельскую ― для этого князь Меншиков был **слишком умен и недостаточно беззаветен (=безогляден)  и пылок**, чтоб рисковать всей армией и, в случае поражения, отдать неприятелю весь Крым. [К. М. Станюкович. ]

Получается, что "беззаветен и целеустремлен"  - это описание человека, который  **пылок, чужд расчетам, способен на риск и действует по принципу "всё ради цели"**.

А вот "самоотверженность и жертвенность" не лучшим образом сочетаются с целеустремленностью и вызывают "ощущения искусственности и противоречивости  этой пары слов".